# Docker complains about invalid certificate after update to v1.7.0

Tags: docker, boot2docker

After updating to Docker v1.7.0 (and also boot2docker), I'm getting the following error when running `docker ps`:

```
x509: certificate is valid for 127.0.0.1, 10.0.2.15, not 192.168.59.103
```

Is this a known issue with this version, and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is a known issue introduced in version 1.7.0 of boot2docker: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/824

## Update to boot2docker 1.7.1

Updating to [boot2docker 1.7.1](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/tag/v1.7.1) fixes this issue, as described [here](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/pull/960).

## Options for boot2docker 1.7.0

It seems to be related to the way the network interfaces are coming up during boot. The following options can be used to fix this.

### Option 1

The fix is to run the following sequence, which adds code to wait for all network interfaces to be present:

```
boot2docker ssh
sudo curl -o /var/lib/boot2docker/profile https://gist.githubusercontent.com/garthk/d5a17007c277aa5c76de/raw/3d09c77aae38b4f2809d504784965f5a16f2de4c/profile
sudo halt
boot2docker up
```

Source (and more details on the code that is downloaded): https://gist.github.com/garthk/d5a17007c277aa5c76de

This has fixed the issue for me, although I had to stop the *boot2docker-vm* through the VirtualBox UI to get a clean start.

The Gist adds the following to the `.profile` file in the boot2docker VM:

```
wait4eth1() {
        CNT=0
        until ip a show eth1 | grep -q UP
        do
                [ $((CNT++)) -gt 60 ] && break || sleep 1
        done
        sleep 1
}
wait4eth1
```

This function waits up to 1 minute for the *eth1* interface to come up.

### Option 2

Another option seems to be to do

```
boot2docker delete
boot2docker init
boot2docker up
```

This will destroy the boot2docker VM - you might lose any customizations you have done.

Answer (score 22):

Simply running this command fixes the issue for me. This was suggested by a Docker employee via GitHub.

`boot2docker ssh sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart`

Unfortunately it needs to be run each time you start boot2docker.

Comment: That's because of the way the network interfaces are started. Once boot2docker has started completely, all of the network interfaces are up - a restart will then use them. The Gist that I linked adds a function that waits for the network interfaces to come up during the first start.

Answer (score 5):

I've found the following "easy" alternative to work. Use a [*shell alias*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29#Unix):

```
alias docker="docker --tlsverify=false"
```

Thanks to [Mark Duncan](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/938#issuecomment-118211836).

Answer (score 0):

From the [troubleshooting](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/faqs/troubleshoot/#example-errors) guide:

```
docker-machine regenerate-certs default

docker-machine restart default
```

And then you're good to go, just run this as usual

```
eval $(docker-machine env default)
```