# boot2docker certificate error

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I download the `boot2docker@1.7.1` and install it through the package wizard. But when I try to run it, it throws me this error:

```
An error occurred trying to connect: Post https://192.168.59.103:2376/v1.19/containers/create: remote error: bad certificate
```

I tried with all [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30980474/docker-complains-about-invalid-certificate-after-update-to-v1-7-0) options, but the issue remains.

Comment: ```boot2docker ssh 'sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart'``` Did you try it?

Comment: It throws me `Need TLS certs for boot2docker,127.0.0.1,10.0.2.15,192.168.59.105
-------------------`

Comment: You need to run 3 ```export``` commands after that. The ```export``` command displays after we run ```boot2docker up```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try running `boot2docker shellinit` to set up your certificates and print some commands to be executed before you run anything using the `docker` command.

On a Mac it would look similar to:

```
Writing /Users/xyz/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/ca.pem
Writing /Users/xyz/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/cert.pem
Writing /Users/xyz/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/key.pem
    export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
    export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/xyz/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
    export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

Here you could simply run `$(boot2docker shellinit)` to set up everything properly.

On Windows you will have some `SET` commands to issue instead of those `export` commands. For further information for Windows users please refer to the [boot2docker documentation](http://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/).